# GDPR Policies. Should someone be "legally registered entrepreneur" to own a website?

Tags: gdpr

I've heard recently heard some rumors that after 25 of May due to change of GDPR policies:

The owner of the website should be legally registered as an entrepreneur in the country where at least 20% of traffic is generated.

**Question:**
1. If that a thing can you please provide some authoritative resources to learn more about.
2. Does it apply also to the people who run small website/blogs only for an informational purpose:

 - Which generate 0 personal income

 - Has insufficient income from advertisements (less then 1k)